# Read the inputs from multiple users and show the inputs in output

Tags: java, oop

The summary of the Question is

**write an application that displays series of 4 survey questions, the survey can be social or political topic ou want and each question should have 3 possible choices. At the end use a dialog box to ask whether the users want to enter (1) enter another set of responses to the same set of question or (2) quit. Continue to accept sets of responses until the user chooses to quit, and then display the results of the survey - for each question indicate how many users choose the results of how many users choose the first, second or third option**

I understood the question but having problems in the last part where you have to show the responses, so I want to ask that how can you take user or many users' inputs and show them in the output while using JOptionPane's method showInputDialog as taking the inputs from
user.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Survey {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String q1, q2, q3, q4;
        int surveyQuestion1,surveyQuestion2,surveyQuestion3,surveyQuestion4 , selection;
        do {
            q1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How you feel" + "\n1. Good" + "\n2. Alright" + "\n3. Bad");
            surveyQuestion1 = Integer.parseInt(q1);

            q2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How is family" + "\n1. Good" + "\n2. Alright" + "\n3. Bad");
            surveyQuestion2 = Integer.parseInt(q2);

            q3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How is home" + "\n1. Good" + "\n2. Alright" + "\n3. Bad");
            surveyQuestion3 = Integer.parseInt(q3);

            q4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How is your life" + "\n1. Good" + "\n2. Alright" + "\n3. Bad");
            surveyQuestion4 = Integer.parseInt(q4);

            selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to set another response ?");
        } while (selection == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
       if(selection == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The people choose " + surveyQuestion1 + " the most from the first question ");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The people choose " + surveyQuestion2 + " the most from the second question ");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The people choose " + surveyQuestion3 + " the most from the third question ");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The people choose " + surveyQuestion4 + " the most from the fourth question ");
       }
    }
}
```

Thank-you :)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. Also, question is not clear. Could you post the _link_ where you got this question?

Comment: On every loop, you overwrite the old answer with the new answer. So instead of showing the answer that was chosen the most, you show the answers of the last one who has voted. You need to store all answers of all people to be able to determine the answer with the most votes for every question.

Comment: Thank you for the response @vish I have edited the question you can check it is from the book Java Programming by Joyce Farrell 4th or 6th edition.

Comment: @McPringle Thank you for the response. Yes, but how to store? use an array or any other storing techniques, because I have searched a lot for storing graphical responses in JOptionPane.

Comment: You don't need to store graphical content. A `JOptionPane`give back a `String`. You can use arrays, lists, maps, databases, whatever you want to store values.

Comment: Ok thank you my good sir

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the best I can with the information you provided, but you should be able to log the inputs in a stack and then take the information out of that stack then put it in the dialog box.

Note: in case you didn't know stack.pop() returns the value it got rid of.

Comment: Thank you Bill Pegerman for the response i will try it

Comment: Also where did you get these questions I'd like to try some of these

Comment: it's a book JAVA PROGRAMMING  by  JOYCE FARRELL ( 4th or 6th edition ) a pretty handy book. I am using it to review and improve my Java programming, also OOP concepts.

Comment: https://github.com/HamzaMohammadKhan/Java-Joyce-Farrell the edition is different you can check in my Github the name will be JAVA_PROGRAMMING_8th

Comment: sorry man busy with something else, will surely show the answer here

Answer (score 2):

I will give you hints, not the code, since this is exercise for you.

> write an application that displays series of 4 survey questions, the survey can be social or political topic ou want and each question should have 3 possible choices. At the end use a dialog box to ask whether the users want to enter (1) enter another set of responses to the same set of question or (2) quit.

So far your code is okay.

> Continue to accept sets of responses until the user chooses to quit,

- This means you need to have storage that is capable of storing 4 answers *per iteration*
- It cannot have static storage because number of times user chooses to continue can vary.

Hint: Think `UDT``class`and something to store as many objects of that maybe from`java.util`

> and then display the results of the survey - for each question indicate how many users choose the results of how many users choose the first, second or third option

This is where question becomes complicated. It does not speak about multiple users till this point. There are two implication of this, either one should be okay:

1. easier: Modify above `UDT``class`**storage** to have multiple answers for *single user* which is stored in expandable data structure possibly from`java.util`

Change the loop in main so that you can choose to change different username, another outer `while\for`

2. much more difficult: implement a way to serialize\store information on disk using something from `java.io` and some storage for example `json` or `xml`
   At the start of application read existing data, get the new data and take average.
   The output in `JOptionPane` should be similar to:

Q1: Number of users
Q2: Number of users
Q3: Number of users
Q4: Number of users

Should be interesting. With option #1 for multiple users it should be done probably in few hours. For #2, you are talking couple days at least.

Comment: Thank you brother @vish this really well explained I will try it Thank you again.

Comment: @HamzaMohammadKhan No problem. If you manage to complete this, I suggest you post to codereview.stackexchange.com. People should be able to help you with code quality there.

Comment: sure will do it